# I can't destroy session

Tags: php, session

I use username and password from my database as my session variable but when I logout I can still visit the secured page with a direct link from my browser what could be the possible cause of this.
Here is my login.php:

```
//initialize the variables
            $username="";
            $password="";
            $_SESSION['username']="";
            $_SESSION['password']="";
            if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && @$_GET["username"] !==""){
                $username=$_POST["username"];
                $password=$_POST["password"];
                if(isset($_POST["username"]) && $_POST["username"]!=="" && isset($_POST["password"]) && $_POST["password"]!==""){
                    //sucuring the data
                    $username=htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST["username"])));
                    $password=htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST["password"])));
                    //checking if user does exist
                    $sql="SELECT email, password FROM ".$db_name.".user WHERE email=\"".$username."\" AND password='".md5($password)."' LIMIT 1";
                    $query=mysql_query($sql,$con);
                    $result=mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
                    //check query to c if is successfully optional
                    if(!$result){
                        print"No result";
                    }else{
                        //if combination found in our database then register session values";
                        $_SESSION['username']=$_POST['username'];
                        $_SESSION['password']=md5($_POST['password']);
                        //check location
                        $sql="SELECT location FROM ".$db_name.". user WHERE email ='".$_POST['username']."' LIMIT 1";
                        $query=mysql_query($sql,$con);
                        $result=mysql_fetch_array($query);
                        //no need of loop since we want only one field/single record/row 
                        $location=$result['location'];
                        header("Location:".$location."");
                    }
                }else{
                //do nothing
                }

            }

        ?>
        <form id="loginFrm" method="post" action="?lgn=getin">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>
                    Inshuz Login
                </legend>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Username
                            <div id="specify">Your email</div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="username" size="40" class="text" value="<?php print $username; ?>">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Password
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="password" name="password" size="40" class="text" value="<?php print $password; ?>">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn" value="Login">
                        <td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

this login.php is included in my index.php below  which is the home page

```
    <?php   session_start(); require_once("includes/functions/url.php"); require_once("includes/config/config.php");?>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>

            </title>
        <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="css/main.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
        <body>
                <div id="wrapper">
                    <div id="header">
                        <div id="nav">
                            <a href="#">Home </a> | <a href="#">About us</a> | <a href="#">Products</a> | <a href="#">Services</a> | <a href="#">Carrers</a>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--end of header-->
                    <div id="mainContent">
                    <div id="RighContent">
                        <?php require_once("includes/pages/".@$page);?>
                    </div><!---RightCont--->
                    <div id="LeftCont">
                        afafhkashf
                    </div><!---leftcont--->
                    </div><!---end of maincontent-->
                    <div id="footer">

                    </div><!--end footer-->
                </div><!--end of wrapper-->
        <body>
    </html>
```

Here is my secure page:

```
<?php session_start();
     require_once("includes/functions/url.php");
    if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
        header("Location: ../");
        exit();
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>

        </title>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="css/main.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
    <body>
            <div id="wrapper">
                <div id="header">
                    <div id="nav">
                        <a href="#">Home </a> | <a href="#">About us</a> | <a href="#">Products</a> | <a href="#">Services</a> | <a href="#">Carrers</a>
                        <?php
                            //show logout
                            if(isset($_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['password'])){
                                print " | <a href=\"includes/pages/logout.php?log=logout\">Logout</a>";
                            }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div><!--end of header-->
                <div id="mainContent">
                <div id="RighContent">
                    <h1>Welcome admin: <?php print @$_SESSION['username']; ?></h1>
                </div><!---RightCont--->
                <div id="LeftCont">
                    afafhkashf
                </div><!---leftcont--->
                </div><!---end of maincontent-->
                <div id="footer">

                </div><!--end footer-->
            </div><!--end of wrapper-->
    <body>


</html>
```

And finally here is my logout page:

```
        <?php 
            ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', false);
            session_start();
             //require_once("includes/functions/url.php");
             if(isset($_GET['log']) && $_GET['log']=="logout"){
                if(isset($_SESSION['username'] , $_SESSION['password']) && !empty($_SESSION['username']) && !empty($_SESSION['password'] )){
                    unset($_SESSION['username']);
                    unset($_SESSION['password']);
                    header("Location: ../../");
                    exit();
                }
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: I don't see `session_destroy()` called ***anywhere*** in your code.

Comment: Also, it may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://www.deprecatedphp.com/mysql_/).

Comment: You have logic unestting `$_SESSION['username']` and `$_SESSION['passowrd']` (why are you storing passwords in the session???)  but if either of those values is blank, the unset code won't run.  Don't check if they are non-empty, just `unset()` them.

Answer (score 3):

Bellow is what you called to be your logout function. Just beacause you unset the `Session[username] and Session[password]` does not mean you destroeyd the session. There is a function called `session_destroy` that does what you want. Please see [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) for information on its usage.

```
<?php 
                ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', false);
                session_start();
                 //require_once("includes/functions/url.php");
                 if(isset($_GET['log']) && $_GET['log']=="logout"){
                    if(isset($_SESSION['username'] , $_SESSION['password']) && !empty($_SESSION['username']) && !empty($_SESSION['password'] )){
                        unset($_SESSION['username']);
                        unset($_SESSION['password']);
                        header("Location: ../../");
                        exit();
                    }
                }
            ?>
```

Comment: The logic on the secure page checks if `$_SESSION['username']` is set. If it has been `unset()` by the logout page, that logic should work without `session_destroy()`.  Those keys are _not_ being `unset()` possibly because the logic in the logout page is faulty.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I saw that. The reason I suggested `session_destroy` is because it is better practice. In the logout page he unsets username and password. If anywhere else (I haven't looked through all the code) he uses `SESSION` to store anything else then he might have conflicts later on. `session_destroy` takes care of all of that and it's much easier then unsetting everything you set in your session.

Comment: Would u please explain why do you think the logout logic is faulty (Michael Berkowski) because am pretty sure with my small understanding that was supposed to work just fine. Could this be the reason http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php#85743 but am using firefox 14 and above

Answer (score 2):

```
unset($_SESSION);
session_destroy();
```

have you tried?

Comment: Sorry originaly sessin_destroy(); was threre i guess i omitted it accidentally when i was inserting my code

Answer (score 1):

Use this in logout page

```
<?php 
session_start();
session_destroy();
session_unset();
header("location:../index.php");

?>
```

AND bellow code for secure page

```
if($_SESSION['uid']==true){
}
    }else{
        header('Location:../');  
  }
```

I will recommend user id instead of using username

Answer (score 0):

Along with all of the above comments on `session_unset()` and `session_destroy()`, you may also want to include something to clear the cache in your browser to prevent someone using the BACK BUTTON, or otherwise reloading the page.

```
header('cache-control: no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate'); // HTTP 1.1.
header('pragma: no-cache'); // HTTP 1.0.
header('expires: 0'); // Proxies.
```

Comment: Guys i think  Michael Berkowski is right i did change my logout page to ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', false);
 session_start();
  //require_once("includes/functions/url.php"); 
  if(isset($_GET['log']) && $_GET['log']=="logout"){
  session_destroy();
  header("Location: ../../");
 } and its work just as i expected it to but i can't explain y